# Dynamic column - how to improve performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

OK, second attempt at the question (first is [How to build virtual columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948940/how-to-build-virtual-columns))

Apologies in advance if this kind of question isn't suitable fo StackOverflow. Feel free to take it down if needed.

The basic question is "what's the best way to have a column whose content is built dynamically".

The code revolves around four tables.

First three (equipment, accessory, association) can be seen as two colums each, an ID and a name.

The goal is to replace the association name with a name built dynamically based on the name of the association components.

The fourth table describes the associations. The association should be seen as a tree, and each "branch" of the tree is represented as a line in this table. Columns are:

- branchID (primary key)
- association ID (int)
- parent node kind (association = 1, equipement = 2,  accessory = 3) (int)
- parent node ID (ID in one of the three other tables) (int)
- kid node kind
- kid node ID

I do have something that works, using a view and a function (the function code follows). However, performance isn't satisfactory.

I see three improvement path:

- minor adjustments through primary keys and indexes (code is significantly faster if there is NO primary key on the 4th table - I haven't been able to explain that)
- fully reviewing the design behind the 4th table (I'm open to ideas)
- replacing the custom function below by... something else! But what could that be?

Sorry for the French names... I chose not to edit the code before posting, assuming that copy/paste errors are worse than translation

- Type = kind
- Enfant = kid
- Jumelage = association
- Numero = name (oops...)
- liens = branches

Thanks.

```
USE [testDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[testjmrFN] 
(
    @JumelageID int
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result varchar(max)

    DECLARE @TypeParent int
    DECLARE @ParentID int
    DECLARE @TypeEnfant int
    DECLARE @EnfantID int
    DECLARE @NumeroEquipement varchar(max)
    DECLARE @NumeroAccessoire varchar(max)

    SET @Result = ''

    DECLARE liens CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
        SELECT l.TypeParent, l.ParentID, l.TypeEnfant, l.EnfantID, e.Numero, a.Numero
        FROM ges_Jumelages_Liens l
        LEFT JOIN ges_Equipements e ON l.EnfantID = e.EquipementID
        LEFT JOIN ges_Accessoires a ON l.EnfantID = a.AccessoireID
        WHERE l.JumelageID = @JumelageID
        ORDER BY LienID

    OPEN liens

    FETCH NEXT FROM liens INTO @TypeParent, @ParentID, @TypeEnfant, @EnfantID, @NumeroEquipement, @NumeroAccessoire
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @TypeParent = 1 AND @TypeEnfant = 2
        BEGIN
            IF @Result <> ''
            BEGIN
                SET @Result = @Result + '§'
            END
            SET @Result = @Result + IsNull(@NumeroEquipement,'')
        END

        IF @TypeParent = 2 AND @TypeEnfant = 3
        BEGIN
            IF @Result <> ''
            BEGIN
                SET @Result = @Result + '~'
            END
            SET @Result = @Result + IsNull(@NumeroAccessoire,'')
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM liens INTO @TypeParent, @ParentID, @TypeEnfant, @EnfantID, @NumeroEquipement, @NumeroAccessoire
    END

    CLOSE liens
    DEALLOCATE liens

    RETURN @Result

END
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: Are you trying to concatonate the values into a long string, also?  What is your desired output?

Comment: @jmr : Provide sample input and output .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you the list that you need.  If you want to concatonate the values into a long string with delimiters based on the cte's `Delimiter` field, see here: [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

```
use master;
go
with cte (TypeParent,ParentID,TypeEnfant,EnfantID,Numero,Delimiter)
as 
(   select      l.TypeParent
                , l.ParentID
                , l.TypeEnfant
                , l.EnfantID
                , e.Numero
                , '§'           as Delimiter
    from        dbo.ges_Jumelages_Liens as l
    join        dbo.ges_Equipements as e 
    on          l.EnfantID = e.EquipmentID
    where       l.TypeParent = 1
    and         l.TypeEnfant = 2
    union all
    select      l.TypeParent
                , l.ParentID
                , l.TypeEnfant
                , l.EnfantID
                , a.Numero
                ,'~'            as Delimiter
    from        dbo.ges_Jumelages_Liens as l
    join        dbo.ges_Accessoires as a 
    on          l.EnfantID = a.EquipmentID 
    where       l.TypeParent = 2
    and         l.TypeEnfant = 3 
)
select          *
from            cte
```

If you need further help, please clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I actually fixed the slowness by disabling "Use actual execution plan" option in  MgmtConsole (I was still debugging it) - but I only found this after implementing your approach.

Comment: Another excellent read on how to combine multiple rows into a single one: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/